Some questions about the UML Comment specification
In section 7.2, page 63 of the PDF file of the UML 2.5.1 specification, the following diagram is presented along with the description of the UML Comment type:

Some questions arise in my mind here:

Why is there a multiplicity of 0..1 on the composition aggregate end owningElement (next to Element)? A Comment must always have an owningElement since it is not a top-level Package;

The association end annotatedElement is *, which means that zero or more Elements can be annotated. It seems to me that this should be 1..* since (a) there must always be an owningElement, and (b) why would an Element own a Comment if it (the owner) was not also an annotatedElement?

I can see why the same Comment might be applied to several different Elements; however, if one Element owns several Comments, how are they distinguishable from each other? A Comment is not a NamedElement, so we cannot query a single Comment by name, and there is no ordering constraint on the set of Comments.

According to its multiplicity, the Comment body attribute can be empty. Does this make any sense?


The latest specification document can be downloaded here:
https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/

A comment actually represents two things:

The description of an element
A note that can be linked to many elements


If it's a description, then it has an owningElement. The description is part of the element, and cannot be shared with other elements.
If it's a note, then it doesn't have an owningElement and it can be used to annotate many elements. (in this case it still has an owner as that relation is inherited from Element)

p. 64, section 7.2.3.1: "Every Element in a model must be owned by exactly one other Element of that model, with the exception of the top-level Packages of the model (...)"

Sorry, that was posted too soon ... I wanted to add that since Comment "IS A" Element, it must have its own owner. Is not owningElement synonymous for owner?

As you can see in the image you posted, owningElement subsets owner these are different relations. Why would you assume owningElement is a synonym for owner? The UML are pretty precise and usually leave no room for interpretation.

Thank you for the explanation, but I have not been able to find the distinction between Comment as "description" and Comment as "note" anywhere in the UML 2.5.1 specification. Can you please quote the relevant page number and/or section where this distinction is made?

The distinction is not made in UML. They only allow it to be owned by a single element, or annotating different elements. In UML tools such as EA this is implemented as shown.

Maybe you could add a note about the note in your little diagram?

I think it is clear that owningElement must also be the owner of a Comment due to the composition relationship, and that the multiplicity should be exactly 1 and not 0..1. IOW, the specification has a defect here. Reasons:

The owningElement is the "whole" and Comment is the "part", and the "whole" is responsible for the lifetime of the "part"; i.e. it must exist;
The quote from the UML specification on p. 64 is quite precise, that there MUST BE exactly one owner of Comment.

What about the Comment body attribute?
